# Make Bootstrap Columns Stop Breaking on Mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get content within a Bootstrap row to scale down rather than break into single columns on mobile. How would I go about this? 
Here is an example of what I have so far:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding:0!important;"> 
        <a class="btn btn-light" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;>
            <h2> title </h2>
            <img src="" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding:0!important;"> 
        <a class="btn btn-light" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;>
            <h2> title </h2>
            <img src="" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding:0!important;"> 
        <a class="btn btn-light" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;>
            <h2> title </h2>
            <img src="" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I open this up on my phone, each column is displayed as a single line on the page. I'd like all three to be on the same row on mobile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Bootstrap-4 has removed all the variants of **`*-xs-*`** classes.

**`col-xs-`** have been dropped in Bootstrap 4 in favor of **`col-`**.
So in order to have three equal width columns on all kinds of devices, use **`col-4`** or just **`col`** instead of **`col-xs-4`**.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#grid-options

---

Use **`p-0`** class instead of the inline padding style for the `a` tags.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

---

Use **`img-fluid`** class instead of the inline css style for the **`img`** elements to make it responsive.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images

---

As you may know, mobile devices have less than `414px` width. But the sum of the `a` tags' width is more than `414px`. Therefore, you should use a **`max-width`** to set their maximum width and use `width: 100%` or `w-100` also.

> The max-width CSS property sets the maximum width of an element. It prevents the used value of the width property from becoming larger than the value specified by max-width. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width

---

In this case, since the row has exactly `12` columns, it is unnecessary to use `justify-content-center`. Therefore, you better remove it.

---

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 p-0">
      <a class="btn btn-light" style="max-width: 200px; width:100%; height: 200px;">
        <h2> title </h2>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100" class="img-fluid">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 p-0">
      <a class="btn btn-light" style="max-width: 200px; width:100%; height: 200px;">
        <h2> title </h2>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100" class="img-fluid">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 p-0">
      <a class="btn btn-light" style="max-width: 200px; width:100%; height: 200px;">
        <h2> title </h2>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100" class="img-fluid">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/djWZJj

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes in your col structure. Bootstrap 4 has changed the breakpoints.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-4" style="padding:0!important;">
    <a class="btn btn-light" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
      <h2> title </h2>
      <img src="" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" style="padding:0!important;">
    <a class="btn btn-light" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
      <h2> title </h2>
      <img src="" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" style="padding:0!important;">
    <a class="btn btn-light" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
      <h2> title </h2>
      <img src="" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

More than likely this has to do with height and width of the images your using. I would suggest just using a max-height and max-width and allow the images to scale to the screen size.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding:0!important;"> 
               <a class="btn btn-light" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;>
                  <h2> title </h2>
                  <img src="" style="max-width:100px; max-height:100px;">
               </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: I think you are right, but could you maybe give an example of the `css` to do this?  This would really improve the answer for people are unfamiliar with the relevant syntax.